# 7zip desktop icon missing

Tags: icons, desktop-icons, 7zip

After reinstalling Ubuntu and 7zip-desktop via snap, I lost the 7zip icon like this.

[image: like this]

All the functionalities work fine, the only annoying part is the missing icon which was there before reinstalling Ubuntu. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu version and Icon theme name??

Comment: 16.04.6, the theme was the default one installed from the iso downloaded from the official site

Comment: Ok, I have to install 16.04.6 and reproduce the issue. 7zip means `p7zip-desktop       16.02.2                      ernytech   -      P7Zip - Desktop` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems the .desktop file does not have the line `Icon=/path/to/icon`.

So manually adding the line will show the Icon.

```
sudo -H gedit /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/p7zip-desktop_p7zip-desktop.desktop
```

Add the line `Icon=</path/to/icon>`

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-SnapInstanceName=p7zip-desktop
Name=P7Zip Desktop
GenericName=P7Zip Desktop - File Manager
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;Utility;Archiving;Compression;
Terminal=false
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/p7zip-desktop_p7zip-desktop.desktop /snap/bin/p7zip-desktop %U
NoDisplay=false
Icon=/home/ubuntu/Downloads/1.png
MimeType=application/gzip;application/x-7z-compressed;application/x-7z-compressed-tar;application/x-arj;application/x-bzip;application/x-bzip-compressed-tar;application/x-bzip1;application/x-bzip1-compressed-tar;application/x-cabinet;application/x-cd-image;application/x-compress;application/x-compressed-tar;application/x-cpio;application/x-deb;application/x-gtar;application/x-gzip;application/x-gzpostscript;application/x-lha;application/x-lhz;application/x-lzma;application/x-lzma-compressed-tar;application/x-ms-wim;application/x-rar;application/x-rar-compressed;application/x-rpm;application/x-tar;application/x-xz;application/x-xz-compressed-tar;application/x-zip;application/x-zip-compressed;application/zip;application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed;
```

[image]

Comment: The actual entry should be `Icon=/snap/p7zip-desktop/current/meta/gui/icon.png` to display icon from the Snap file instead of some detached picture.
Link back to the issue: https://github.com/ErnyTech/p7zip/issues/14